# Is there a for i in ("foo", "bar", "baz") construct in VBA?

Tags: vba, for-loop, iteration

I have to iterate over a constant list of strings. As far as I know, there is no

```
for item in ("foo", "bar", "baz")
   doSth(item)
next item
```

I was wondering how I can elegantly program such a construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegantly? You decide.

Try:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Variant

    For Each x In Array("foo", "bar", "bas")
        Debug.Print x
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit generic, but yes, you can do that using `For Each`. I'll paste some code of my own, and you'll see how it can work:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim tempFolderStr As String
    Dim tempFullStr As String
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim fs As Object

(...)

    Set objFolder = fs.GetFolder(tempFolderStr)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        tempFullStr = tempFolderStr & objFile.name
        Call Delete_File(tempFullStr)
    Next objFile

End Sub
```

This will iterate over every file it finds in the folder tempFolderStr.

I'll leave the link to the apropriate MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx